# getObjectById not work TypeError: scene.getObjectById is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new programmer on Javascript and three.js. 
I got an error getObjectById not work TypeError: scene.getObjectById is not a function

I try to access an object in the three.js scene by its id which i saved in array in location tre[m][1].

this is my function also the problem appear in call by name not only by id

> function crvtre(){
>
> ```
> //  alert("I enter crvtre");
>       for(var m=0; m<max; m++){
>           for(var n=m+1; n<max; n++){
>           // we should add in (tre[m][0] != tre[n][0]) to draw between trees only and inside one tree
>               if(tre[m][5]==0 && tre[n][5]==0 && (tre[m][0] != tre[n][0])){
>
>                   var object = scene.getObjectById(tre[m][1],true);
>                   console.log(object.userData[1])
>                }
>            }
>       }
>       //animate();
> }
> ```

it seems very trivial problem but I got sick to know the reason, so any one has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You get that because `getObjectById` is not a method of `THREE.Scene`

If you want to access an object in a scene, and you know where the object is, you just have it accesssing it:

```
var object = tre[m][1];
```

Comment: Thank you , I just build the following function depending on the source code of getObjectById and its work                                                                                                                                                                                                                             `function getbyid( id, recursive ){
 
 
   for ( var i = 0, l = scene.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

   var child = scene.children[ i ];
            console.log("I am child of scene"+child.id );
   if ( child.id === id ) {

    return child;

   }
  }`